# Symfony2 twig escaping strategy on dev and prod environment

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I have the file `index.html.twig`.

In this file I include the another file: `{% include 'MyBundle:Test:_test.js.twig' %}`

`_test.js.twig` file has only one line: `{{ test_var }}`

In controller I pass the `test_var`: `return array('test_var' => '"test"');`

The problem is that if I use a different environment (dev and prod) sf will use the different escaping strategies for variables.

In dev I see the output: `\x22test\x22` (it's a js escaping strategy)

In prod: `&quot;test&quot;` (it's a html escaping strategy)

Why? I thought that dev and prod environments should work equally.

Comment: With dev and prod environment, do you mean different machines or "just" the difference between the app.php and the app_dev.php?

Comment: I mean app.php (production env) and app_dev.php (development env)

Answer (score 1):

I can't to say why. I need to see your config.yml and config_dev.yml.

But you can write your `MyBundle:Test:_test.js.twig` like this:

```
{{ test_var|e('js') }}
```

or:

```
{% autoescape 'js' %}
    {{ test_var }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my question is why. I didn't change the default sf config. So my configuration is default for symfony 2.1

Comment: Ok, I will taste it on Sunday.